How to upper bound $ (\frac{en}{k})(\frac{2e}{\epsilon})^{\epsilon/2}(\frac{4ekd}{\epsilon n})^{\epsilon^2 d/4}$?
I am working on upper bound the following quantity:

Let $8\le d\le n, \epsilon\in (0,1), k\ge 2$. If $\epsilon^2\ge \frac{\max\{8, \log d\}}{d}$ and $k\le \frac{\epsilon n}{3eC_1 d}$ for some large absolute constant $C_1>0$, then we have
$$
\left(\frac{en}{k}\right)\left(\frac{2e}{\epsilon}\right)^{\epsilon/2}\left(\frac{4ekd}{\epsilon n}\right)^{\epsilon^2 d/4}\le \left(\frac{C_1kd}{\epsilon n}\right)^{\epsilon^2d/8}
$$

Question: (1) How do we get this upper bound based on our assumption on $\epsilon$?
(2) Can we get sharp lower bound for $\epsilon^2$? Say $\epsilon^2\ge \frac{1}{d^{2}}$?

For (1), I try to show this inequality... This inequality is equivalent as
$$
\left(\frac{en}{k}\right)\left(\frac{2e}{\epsilon}\right)^{\epsilon/2}\left(\frac{C_1kd}{\epsilon n}\right)^{\epsilon^2 d/8}\le 1
$$
I am stuck on here...

I tried to simplify the question and used rather precise relaxations.
Unfortunately, under them I obtained a negative answer and I expect that the answer is negative.
I think that for a positive answer we need either to provide $d>e^4$ or
to diminish some factors at the left-hand side.
Put $a=\frac kn$. Then $0<a\le \frac{\epsilon}{3eC_1d}$ and we have to ensure
$$
\left(\frac{e}a\right)\left(\frac{2e}{\epsilon}\right)^{\epsilon/2}\left(\frac{4ead}{\epsilon }\right)^{\epsilon^2 d/4}\le \left(\frac{C_1ad}{\epsilon}\right)^{\epsilon^2d/8}
$$
$$
\left(\frac{e}a\right)\left(\frac{2e}{\epsilon}\right)^{\epsilon/2}\left(4e\right)^{\epsilon^2 d/4}
\left(\frac{ad}{\epsilon}\right)^{\epsilon^2 d/8}
\le C_1^{\epsilon^2d/8}.
$$
The degree of $a$ is $\epsilon^2 d/8-1\ge 0$, so the left-hand side nondecreases if $a$ increases. Therefore we have to ensure the inequality when $a=\frac{\epsilon}{3eC_1d}$, that is that
$$e\cdot\left(\frac{2e}{\epsilon}\right)^{\epsilon/2}\left(4e\right)^{\epsilon^2 d/4}
\left(\frac{d}{\epsilon}\right)^{\epsilon^2 d/8}\left(\frac{\epsilon}{3eC_1d}\right)^{\epsilon^2 d/8-1}
\le C_1^{\epsilon^2d/8}$$
$$e\cdot\left(\frac{2e}{\epsilon}\right)^{\epsilon/2}\left(4e\right)^{\epsilon^2 d/4}
\left(\frac{d}{\epsilon}\right)\left(\frac{1}{3eC_1}\right)^{\epsilon^2 d/8-1}
\le C_1^{\epsilon^2d/8}$$
$$e\cdot\left(\frac{2e}{\epsilon}\right)^{\epsilon/2}\left(4e\right)^{\epsilon^2 d/4}
\left(\frac{d}{\epsilon}\right)\left(\frac{1}{3e}\right)^{\epsilon^2 d/8-1}
\le C_1^{\epsilon^2d/4-1}$$
$$\left(\frac{2e}{\epsilon}\right)^{\epsilon/2}\cdot 4^{\epsilon^2 d/4}\cdot
\left(\frac{d}{\epsilon}\right)\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{\epsilon^2 d/8-1}\cdot e^{\epsilon^2 d/8+2}
\le C_1^{\epsilon^2d/4-1}$$
$$2^{\epsilon^2 d/2+\epsilon/2}\cdot\epsilon^{-1-\epsilon/2}\cdot d\cdot 3^{1-\epsilon^2 d/8}\cdot e^{\epsilon^2 d/8+2+\epsilon/2}\le C_1^{\epsilon^2d/4-1}.$$
Put $C=2^{1/2}\cdot 3\cdot e^{2+1/2}=51.68\dots$. Then the left-hand side of the inequality is at most
$$C\cdot\left(\frac {16e}3\right)^{\epsilon^2 d/8}\cdot\epsilon^{-1-\epsilon/2}\cdot d,$$
so it suffices to bound the latter by $C_1^{\epsilon^2d/4-1}$.
$$C\cdot\left(\frac {16e}3\right)^{\epsilon^2 d/8}\cdot\epsilon^{-1-\epsilon/2}\cdot d\le C_1^{\epsilon^2d/4-1}$$
$$C_1\cdot C\cdot\left(\frac {16e}3\right)^{\epsilon^2 d/8}\cdot\epsilon^{-1-\epsilon/2}\cdot d\le C_1^{\epsilon^2d/4}$$
$$C_1\cdot C\cdot\epsilon^{-1-\epsilon/2}\cdot d\le \left(\frac {3C_1^2}{16e}\right)^{\epsilon^2d/8}$$
Put $C_2=\frac {3C_1^2}{16e}$. Then we have to ensure
$$D\cdot C_2^{1/2}\cdot\epsilon^{-1-\epsilon/2}\cdot d\le C_2^{\epsilon^2d/8},$$
where $D=C\sqrt{\frac {16e}3}=196.79\dots$.
Now we use that $\epsilon^2d\ge \log d$ (I assume that $\log$ means $\log_e$). Then is suffices to ensure
$$D\cdot C_2^{1/2}\cdot\epsilon^{-1-\epsilon/2}\cdot d\le C_2^{\log d/8}=d^{\log C_2/8}.$$
Since $\epsilon\ge 2^{3/2} d^{-1/2}$, $\epsilon^{-1}\le 2^{3/2} d^{1/2}$, so
$$\epsilon^{-1-\epsilon/2}\le \left(2^{3/2} d^{1/2}\right)^{1+\epsilon/2}\le 2^{9/4}d^{3/4}.$$
So it suffices to ensure
$$E\cdot C_2^{1/2} d^{7/4}\le d^{\log C_2/8},$$
where $E=D\cdot 2^{9/4}=936.13\dots$. For the latter we have to provide
$$E\cdot C_2^{1/2} \le 8^{\log C_2/8-7/4}.$$
Unfortunately, this is impossible because if $C_2>1$ then $$8^{\log C_2/8}=C_2^{\log 8/8}<C_2^{1/2}.$$

Thank you! Yes, we can assume that $d>e^4$ (here I want to choose $d$ and $n$ very large). Can I ask if we can reduce the lower for $\epsilon$?
